# invisible controls in asp.net takes up space in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I have an `ASP.NET` web application. I have one `TextBox` (txtProductName) and one `DropDownList`(ddlChanges) visible at the time of page load. Also there is a `TextBox`(txtDeliveryStatus) and a `Label` (lblDeliveryStatus) invisible at page load.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" MaxLength="8" Width="60" />

<asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryStatus" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden;">Delivery Status : </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDeliveryStatus" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" Style="visibility: hidden;"/>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlChanges" CssClass="selectstyle" onchange="javascript:ddlChangesChanged();"> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select -- " Value="-1"></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="Status Change" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Product Name Change" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>       
    <asp:ListItem Text="Category Change" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I will make the `Label` and `TextBox`for delivery status visible when user selects Status Change from the `DropDownList`. But the problem is that the `Label` and `TextBox` for delivery status are invisible and still they take up some space on the page between visible controls.

How to remove that space of invisible controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `display` attribute:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryStatus" runat="server" Style="display: none;">Delivery Status : </asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDeliveryStatus" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" Style="display: none;"/>
```

For completeness you can check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

Comment: It worked for the space issue. but now my controls are on the new line. If I apply float:left then also the alignment changes.

Comment: @nrvbha why don't you place the hidden controls after every other controls. I mean, they are hidden...

Comment: Sorry. It worked. Used $("#lblDeliveryStatus").css("display", "inline-block"); instead of $("#lblDeliveryStatus").css("display", "block");

Answer (score 1):

the reason the white space is still showing after you control.Visible = false is because the "br" newLine tags are remaining.  Wrap them with your button tag and hide both to truly remove the white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visible attribute of control.
To hide:

```
Control.Visibile=false;
```

Whenever you want to display

```
Control.Visible=true;
```